# Show only the outlines of graphic primitives

Tags: graphics

I want to go from

```
Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 3}], Blue, Polygon[{{1, 1}, {3, 1}, {2, 2}}]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

to

[image]

I have rather clumsily written:

```
RectangleToLines[r_] := With[{n = Flatten @ r},
  Line[{{n[[1]], n[[2]]}, {n[[3]], n[[2]]}, {n[[3]], n[[4]]}, {n[[1]],n[[4]]}, {n[[1]], n[[2]]}}]
  ]

RectangleToLines[{{0, 0}, {1, 3}}]
```

> Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 3}, {0, 3}, {0, 0}}]

and similar with the triangle. Terrible, because I would end up with many "FormToLines"-definitions.

I feel - that especially with **V10** - there should be a much cleverer way to do this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A little simpler & shorter, but effectively the same as the [answer by ybeltukov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59086/18476):

```
g = Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 3}], Blue, 
     Polygon[{{1, 1}, {3, 1}, {2, 2}}]}, Frame -> True];

g /. c_RGBColor :> Sequence[EdgeForm[c], Transparent]
```

> [image]

---

Based on the excellent comments, a version that works for all color directives, draws no faces instead of transparent ones and uses [`Directive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Directive.html?q=Directive), which is more typical for Graphics, instead of the more general [`Sequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html?q=Sequence).

```
g /. c_?ColorQ :> Directive[EdgeForm[c], FaceForm[]]
```

Comment: +1 You could also use `Directive`

Comment: You can also use FaceForm[] instead of Transparent.

Comment: You can also use `c_?ColorQ` so that `Hue`, `CMYKColor`, `GrayLevel`, etc. are all recognized.

Answer (score 10):

There is a brute force solution with substitution all colors to `EdgeForm` colors and putting `FaceForm[None]` at the beginning

```
g = Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 3}], Blue, 
    Polygon[{{1, 1}, {3, 1}, {2, 2}}]}, Frame -> True];
Graphics[Prepend[#, FaceForm[None]] /. c_RGBColor :> EdgeForm[c], ##2] & @@ g
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

An even bruter force approach using new region functions

```
g1 = Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 3}], Blue, 
    Polygon[{{1, 1}, {3, 1}, {2, 2}}]}, Frame -> True];

Show[
 RegionPlot[
    ImplicitRegion[
     RegionMember[#[[1]], {x, y}],
     {x, y}],
    PlotStyle -> None,
    BoundaryStyle -> #[[2]]] & /@
  Thread[{
    Cases[g1, r_?(RegionQ[#] &), Infinity],
    Cases[g1, rgb_RGBColor, Infinity]}],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `EdgeForm` and `FaceForm` directly instead?

```
points = {{0, 0}, {4, 0}, {3, 3}};
triangle = Triangle[points];
circle = Insphere[points];

Graphics[{
  circle,
  {
    FaceForm[{Yellow,Opacity[0]}],
    EdgeForm[{Thick,Black}],
    triangle
  }
}]
```

[image: incircle]